# Avoid form resubmit on page refresh w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a good way to avoid form submission when the page is reloaded?

I am thinking of adding a jQuery submit functionality only when a button is clicked but perhaps I am overdoing this.

Just wanted to check.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you are looking to a button reload the page without resending the form so that they can send another with new information?

IE: contact form submitted.
Now you want to "send another" so you need to reload the page to present the form again.

You can use a jQuery function to reload the page instead of refresh.  Just create a refresh function that will "redirect" the page to the same page.

if using jQuery

```
var reloadPage = window.location.href;
$('#[button]).on('click',function(){
    window.location.replace(reloadPage);
});
```

With PHP

PHP code to get page

```
<?php 
  $url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

jQuery to redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#[button]).on('click',function(){
       window.location.replace('<?php echo $url;?>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the form successfully, perform a redirect. It doesn't matter where to, but it'll clear the $_POST.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php');
```

In your case, it sounds like you want to redirect to the page you're already on. Append a $_GET parameter to the URL if you want to display a confirmation message.

This will prevent a form resubmit when the user reloads the page.

Answer (score 1):

POST Redirect GET.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

If you add jQuery into the mix, people without javascript won't be able to use your form anymore. Your best solution really is to make sure a form can't be send twice, in your back-end.

Comment: I used to wonder if there are still really users out there without JS support. I decided not to worry about those and added a lot of JS functionality. Unfortunately if they do not support JS they won't get too far on my page. I suppose I opted for the downfall of a few for the benefit of the many. :)

Comment: True, but I keep this rule in my mind, because when I encounter such a problem, I'm often better off refactoring my logic than my front-end.